# Javascript onClick picks the wrong element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
    for(let x = 0; x < 10; x++){container_For_Dices.push(Math.round(Math.random()*10))}
let Ids  = ["Dice1","Dice2","Dice3","Dice4","Dice5","Dice6","Dice7","Dice8","Dice9","Dice10"]
let id = -1
container_For_Dices= container_For_Dices.map((value=>{
    id +=1
    return(
        <button
         className="w-20 h-20 m-2 rounded-lg bg-slate-300 content-center pt-4 shadow shadow-gray-500 text-4xl font-bold dices"
         id={Ids[id]}
         onClick={()=>{
            var element = document.getElementById(`${Ids[id]}`)
            element.classList.remove("dices")
            element.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
            }} >
            {value}
        </button>
    )
}))
```

The problem is definitely in the onClick part, but I have no clue how to fix it. If I click on one of the elements, the 10th element gets picked. I already checked that every element got the correct id...

Comment: Please, provide full example of code, so we can debug and help you.

Comment: this is actually everything you need to know

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: the issue is the scope of `id` ... try `container_For_Dices.map((value, id) =>` instead of that crazy thing you do - and why do you do the double `((value => ...... code .... ))` - not an issue, you're just wasting `()` :p

Answer (score 0):

Try passing event argument `onClick={(e)=>{` and extract element from event `var element = e.target;`

```
<button
         className="w-20 h-20 m-2 rounded-lg bg-slate-300 content-center pt-4 shadow shadow-gray-500 text-4xl font-bold dices"
         id={Ids[id]}
         onClick={(e)=>{
            var element = e.target;
            element.classList.remove("dices")
            element.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
            }} >
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded....